# Weak convergence and compact embeddings

Tags: functional-analysis, compactness, weak-convergence

Assume that $X,Y$ are Banach spaces, such that $X$ is compactly embedded into $Y$. Further, let $f_n: [0,T]\rightarrow X$ be a sequence of functions such that

\begin{equation}
\sup_{t \in [0,T]}|\langle f_n(t) - f(t),g \rangle_{X \times X'}| \rightarrow 0 \ \ \ \forall g \in X'. 
\end{equation}

Now I want to show that

\begin{equation}
\sup_{t \in [0,T]} \| f_n(t) - f(t) \|_Y \rightarrow 0,
\end{equation}

but i don't know how. By the above given weak convergence for fixed $t$ and the compact embedding we know of course that

\begin{equation}
\| f_n(t) - f(t) \|_Y \rightarrow 0 \ \ \ \forall t \in [0,T]
\end{equation}

but I don't see why this convergence also holds true in the supremum. I also searched for embedding theorems which might give us immediately that C([0,T],X) is compactly embedded in C([0,T],Y), but I can't find anything. The continuity of this embedding is clear, but I can't see that it is really compact.

Thank you for any hints.

Comment: The compact inclusion maps bounded sets into relatively compact sets. Weakly convergent sequences are bounded.

Comment: Yes, but this only gives us the convergence for fixed $t$, right? To conclude the desired uniform convergence from this, we need that $C([0,T];X)$ is compactly embedded in $C([0,T];Y)$ and I don't see why this is true.

Comment: $f_n\to f$ holds uniformly in $(Y,\sigma(Y,Y'))$ and everything (i.e., $\{f_n(t):n\in\mathbb N, t\in [0,T]\}$) is contained in a norm-compact subset of $Y$ on which the weak and the norm-topologies coincide.

Comment: By the way, the embedding $C([0,T];X) \hookrightarrow C([0,T];Y)$ is *not* compact because it "is" the identity on the infinite dimensional closed subspace $C([0,T])$ of $C([0,T];X)$.

Comment: I think I get it, I'll try to summarize (as I'm not very familiar with the term weak topology): we have given uniform convergence of $f_n$ in $(X, \sigma (X,X'))$ and as $X \subset Y$ also in $(Y, \sigma (Y,Y'))$. Since weakly convergent sequences are bounded and the embedding of $X$ into $Y$ is compact, we have that $\{f_n(t)\}$ belongs to a norm-compact subset of $Y$. On such sets we know in general that weak and strong topology (and thus convergence) coincide, so we may improve the uniform convergence in $(Y, \sigma (Y,Y'))$ to uniform convergence on $Y$ wrt the norm topology.

Comment: Is this correct? Thank you very much for your help by the way!

Comment: Correct. You're welcome.